# How std::function works

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

You know, we can wrap or store a lambda function to a `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
int main()
{
    std::function<float (float, float)> add = [](float a, float b)
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        return a + b;
    };

    std::cout << add(1, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

My question is around `std::function`, as you can see it is a template class but it can accept any kind of **function signature**.

For example `float (float, float)` in this form `return_value (first_arg, second_arg)`.

What's the structure of `std::function` and how does it accept a function signature like `x(y,z)` and how it works with it? Is `float (float, float)` a new valid expression in C++?

Comment: Look up type erasure in C++.

Comment: You can always open your compiler's `<function>` header (I believe all major compilers ship std headers as C++ code) and inspect it, or have a look at [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html).

Comment: @Angew: Yes, very educational, +1. I think `std::function` touches on just about every aspect of the C++ language...

Comment: For an easier mental exercise, try to understand how `std::bind` works...

Comment: You can check implementation at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14741161/1762344

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It uses some [type erasure technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques).

One possibility is to use mix subtype polymorphism with templates. Here's a simplified version, just to give a feel for the overall structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct function;

template <typename Result, typename... Args>
struct function<Result(Args...)> {
private:
    // this is the bit that will erase the actual type
    struct concept {
        virtual Result operator()(Args...) const = 0;
    };

    // this template provides us derived classes from `concept`
    // that can store and invoke op() for any type
    template <typename T>
    struct model : concept {
        template <typename U>
        model(U&& u) : t(std::forward<U>(u)) {}

        Result operator()(Args... a) const override {
            t(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        }

        T t;
    };

    // this is the actual storage
    // note how the `model<?>` type is not used here    
    std::unique_ptr<concept> fn;

public:
    // construct a `model<T>`, but store it as a pointer to `concept`
    // this is where the erasure "happens"
    template <typename T,
        typename=typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_convertible<
                decltype( t(std::declval<Args>()...) ),
                Result
            >::value
        >::type>
    function(T&& t)
    : fn(new model<typename std::decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(t))) {}

    // do the virtual call    
    Result operator()(Args... args) const {
        return (*fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

(Note that I overlooked several things for the sake of simplicity: it cannot be copied, and maybe other problems; don't use this code in real code)

Comment: @Martinho, where is the definition of 'Unqualified'?

Comment: @xmllmx It's an alias template that removes all qualifiers (const, volatile, &, and &&) from a type. Same as `Bare` here: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/05/29/type-traits-galore.html#bare_types (I have since changed my mind and found Unqualified to be a better name :)

Comment: @xmllmx, actually, scratch that. It should be `std::decay` instead (it simulates pass-by-value semantics, which is what I want: I want to store by value). They are similar, but not quite the same here.

Comment: @Martinho, the argument name 'args' is lacked in function::operator (). Please add it to make the code complete.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I couldn't resist fixing the constructor.  :)  Free free to rollback, probably too complex for this question.

Comment: @Yakk that's ok. Note my edit, btw: if you use declval, you don't need to forward; declval is pretty much forward without a value to forward: its return type already has the right value category.

Comment: How is this simplified? I.e. what can it not do that it should do?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Should the code, instead of `t(std::forward<Args>(a)...);` be `return t(std::forward<Args>(a)...);` ?

Comment: How would this class be used, using it like std::function results in a compile error?

Comment: @paulm I don't know. I never actually used this class. I only wrote it for explanatory purposes. See the note at the end.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Isn't `concept` actually missing a virtual destructor? Thinking on functors with non-trivial destructors. Excellent answer, by the way.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I assume you’re missing `return` from `model`’s `operator()`?