# C++11 lambda can be assigned to std::function with incorrect signature

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, rvalue-reference

The following compiles and runs (under Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 and Visual C++ 2015):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct s { int x; };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::function<void (s &&)> f = [](const s &p) { std::cout << p.x; };
    f(s {1});
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the assignment `std::function<void (s &&)> f = [](const s &p) { std::cout << p.x; };` generate an error? A function accepting an rvalue reference should not have the same signature as a function accepting a const lvalue reference, should it? Dropping the `const` from the lambda's declaration does generate an error as expected.

Comment: gcc 5.1 does not complain either.

Comment: Nit-pick: You're not assigning to a `std::function`. Although the syntax is very similar, `std::function<..> f = ..;` is an initialization rather than an assignment, since it defines a new object.

Comment: This is akin to the ordinary contravariance of function parameters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To expand on the existing comment and answer:

The point of `std::function<R(A...)>` is that it can wrap any function or functor that can be called with `A...` and have the result stored in an `R`.

So, for example,

```
std::function<int(int)> f = [](long l) { return l; };
```

is just peachy.

So what you have to ask yourself when you see something like this: if you have a lambda taking `const T &`, and you have an expression of type `T &&` (or, more accurately, you have an xvalue of type `T`), can you use that expression to call the lambda?

Yes, you can.

And if you can, then `std::function` is supposed to be able to store that functor. That's pretty much the main point of `std::function`.

Comment: this also applies to class hierarchies, `std::function<void(Derived*)> f = [](Base *){ };`

Comment: Nice answer, +1, it's the first time when I hear this. How does it work behind the scenes? Type erasure?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, see for example [R. Martinho Fernandes's excellent answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936539/how-stdfunction-works) for details.

Comment: @vsoft As an example, there is some object that has the described signature that std function has, and in it it calls the lambda.

Comment: @hvd, thanks for the link, addresses exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 8):

Please take this with a grain of salt. This is what I understand, but I am not sure.

Consider the following output:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout <<  std::is_convertible<s &&, s&>::value << std::endl;       //false                                                      
  std::cout <<  std::is_convertible<s &&, const s&>::value << std::endl; //true                                                     

  std::cout <<  std::is_convertible<const s &, s&&>::value << std::endl; //false                                                     
  return 0;
}
```

This shows that it is possible to convert a `s &&` to a `const s&`. This is why the `std::function`'s assignment is ok.

> Dropping the const from the lambda's declaration does generate an
>   error as expected.

Indeed this is because (as shown before), converting a `s &&` to a `s &` is not possible.

In the same way, trying the opposite:

`std::function<void (const s &)> f = [](s &&p) { std::cout << p.x; };` would fail because it is not possible to convert a `const s&`
 to a `s &&`.