# Different overloads with std::function parameters is ambiguous with bind (sometimes)

Tags: c++, overloading, c++14, std-function, stdbind

I have two overloads of a function `foo` which take different `std::function`s which results in an ambiguity issue for the latter when used with the result of a `std::bind`.  I don't understand why *only* this is ambiguous.

```
void foo(std::function<void(int)>) {}
void foo(std::function<int()>) {}

void take_int(int) { }
int ret_int() { return 0; }
```

When using `int()` with a `bind` function I get an ambiguity error

```
foo(std::bind(ret_int)); // ERROR
```

With the gcc-5.1 error (and similar with clang)

```
error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
  foo(std::bind(ret_int));
  ^~~
note: candidate function
void foo(std::function<void(int)>) {}
     ^
note: candidate function
void foo(std::function<int()>) {}
```

However all of the following work

```
foo(std::bind(take_int, _1));
foo(take_int);

foo(ret_int);
foo([](){ return ret_int(); });

struct TakeInt {
  void operator()(int) const { }
};

struct RetInt {
  int operator()() const { return 0; }
};

foo(TakeInt{});
foo(RetInt{});
```

Looking at the `std::function` constructor

```
template< class F > 
function( F f );
```

it would make sense to me that any function with multiple overloads on different `std::function` types should have ambiguities, but it's only an issue with the call to bind.  I then thought "maybe there's some magic happening to handle function types and lambdas and it doesn't deal with actual classes," but it handles those too.

There's a note on en.cppreference that says [since c++14]

> This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227097/c11-lambda-can-be-assigned-to-stdfunction-with-incorrect-signature and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146749/overload-resolution-with-stdfunction/22147471#22147471

Answer (score 4):

The problem exists in how bind is allowed to be called.  As [cppreference states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.

In other words, you need to pass *at least* as many arguments as the underlying callable expects.

This means that the following is valid

```
int f();
auto b = std::bind(f);
b(1, 2, 3); // arguments aren't used
```

So saying

```
auto b = std::bind(ret_int)
b(1);
```

Works, with the `1` discarded, therefore the following is valid, and overload selection becomes ambiguous

```
std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(ret_int);
```

The inverse is not true, however

```
std::function<int()> f = std::bind(take_int);
```

because `take_int` cannot be called with no arguments.

Takeaway: lambda > bind

Comment: Where in the standard does it say that excess arguments are discarded? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I don't know I stopped on cppreference on this one.  I'm looking now too

Comment: I think I found it although it might seem a little far-fetched: N4431 20.9.2/4.  `A forwarding call wrapper is a call wrapper that can be called with an arbitrary argument list and delivers the arguments to the wrapped callable object as references`. The note even uses variadics.