# C++11 binding std function to a overloaded static method

Tags: c++11, std-function

this question seems a little bit silly to me but I can't find any similar question so sorry if it's trivial

let's say we have a struct:

```
struct C {
  static void f(int i) { std::cerr <<  (i + 15) << "\n"; }
  static void f(std::string s) { std::cerr <<  (s + "15") << "\n"; }
};
```

now somewhere else:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = C::f; // this does not compile
void (*f2)(std::string s) = C::f;   // this compiles just fine
```

the error I'm getting is

> error: conversion from ‘’ to
>   non-scalar type ‘std::function’ requested

is there any way to use std::function in such context? what am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> std::function<void(int)> f1 = C::f; // this does not compile
> ```

`C::f` is an *overload set* which does not have an address. You can create a wrapper `FunctionObject` around it:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = [](int x){ return C::f(x); };
```

---

> ```
> void (*f2)(std::string s) = C::f;   // this compiles just fine
> ```

This line compiles because you're "selecting" the `std::string` overload of the `C::f` *overload set* by explicitly assigning it to a `void(*)(std::string)` pointer.

You can do the same thing for `f1`:

```
 std::function<void(int)> f1 = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&C::f);
```

Comment: I sort of understood that (well not really, maybe *guessed* that it is the cause). but why can't the compiler infer the selected overload when using std::function?

Comment: @user2717954: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393285/stdfunction-fails-to-distinguish-overloaded-functions , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172921/different-overloads-with-stdfunction-parameters-is-ambiguous-with-bind-someti