# Passing template arguments as target type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In this shortened example (not real world code), I'm attempting to call `Callback` with an `int &`, however, when going via the `CallMethod` method, the template parameter is interpreted as an `int`, meaning it can't convert it to the target parameter type.

Is this possible? I know I can cast the parameter to the correct type when calling `CallMethod`, however I'd like the solution to be implicit if possible.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Callback(int &value)
{
    value = 42;
}

template <typename Method, typename ...Params>
void CallMethod(Method method, Params ...params)
{
    method(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    CallMethod(&Callback, value);

    cout << "Value: " << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @leemes Oops, thanks, that was just a typo in my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't correctly forwarding your arguments. In order to make use of perfect-forwarding `std::forward` should operate on forwarding references, which are when you have an rvalue reference in a deduced context. Your `CallMethod` function should look like this:

```
template <typename Method, typename ...Params>
void CallMethod(Method method, Params&& ...params)
{
    method(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/PzQOvJ)

Comment: *"std::forward should operate on forwarding references"*, it's not true in general, for non-forwarding-reference types it just turns arguments taken by value into rvalues, which can then let you take advantage of move-constructing parameters taken by value in a function the argumnts are *forwarded* into

Comment: @PiotrS. I don't completely understand what the use-case is, do you have a link or code sample I could look at?

Comment: A classic example is [How std::function works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14936539/3953764)