# std::function type and template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, std-function

I'm new to C++ and I'm learning about lambdas,functors and callables, and I know that there's a wrapper class, namely `std::function` that allows callables of different types to be stored and called (as long as the have the same call signature,or function type).

Now, I understand that you can have function with function type parameters that are really just function pointer parameters as in :

```
void fun(int,int*(int,int&));
```

which is nothing more than a function that takes an int and a function pointer to a function like `int *f(int,int&)`,even if the language allows me to pass a function as an argument (with or without the ampersand).Infact, the function parameter list might as well be written as:

```
void fun(int,int*(*)(int,int&));
```

Now,back to the `std::function` type

I know that I can instantiate `std::function` with a function type and that allows any kind of callable to be passed to the wrapper. But, a function type is not a type I can use as a template type argument in any instantiation such as:

```
std::vector<int(int)> f_vec;
```

instead, I should make a vector of function pointers

```
std::vector<int(*)(int)> f_vec;
```

and that would allow me to insert pointers to function,but not functors or lambdas.

So, my question is, how can I instantiate a template with a type argument like a function type?? what's happening under the hood in the library `std::function` type.I mean a function type seems to me a type I cannot use in templates?? pleas can you make things a little clearer,as I'm just beginning to learn these topics. Thanks

Comment: [How std::function works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14936539/3953764)

Comment: The type of template of `std::vector` has different requirement than the one for `std::function`.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why you cannot write `std::vector<int(int)>` is not something fundamental about using function types as template parameters. That's perfectly valid. It's just what `std::vector<T>` *does* with the `T` (like operate on it by value) which makes `std::vector<int(int)>` illegal.

This can be [shown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df47475f13b0b2b2) by using `std::vector<int(int)>` in a context where nothing bad happens, such as this:

```
typedef std::vector<int(int)> StillOk;
StillOk *p = nullptr;
```

As long as the template doesn't actually try to do anything illegal with `int(int)`, it's fine.

So, as long as your template deals with its template parameter in a way which is legal for function types, you can use it with function types. Here's a hypothetical example:

```
template <class T>
struct MyPointer
{
  T *p;
  T& operator* () const { return *p; }
};
```

It's now perfectly legal to instantiate `MyPointer<int(int)>` and use its `operator *`, because it will only ever involve expressions of type `int (*)(int)` and `int (&)(int)`. [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7453f524e407a11)

And that's pretty much also what `std::function<T>` does with its `T`—only things which are legal with a function type.

Comment: ok, so I understand that the topic is indeed deeper and that I need to delve into it a "little" more... but now you got me confused, I know about function pointers, but function references??

Comment: @Luca Yes, function references exist as well. `void (&alias)() = foo;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: and what's their use? I mean, if I define a function parameter of function type, that is treated automatically as a function pointer, so how do function references fit into the picture?

Comment: @Luca The question goes the other way round - what would anyone get from forbidding them (apart from complicating compilers)?

Comment: yes, but it just seems to me that the usage for the two types kind of overlaps?

Comment: @Luca So does usage of `int` and `long`, to a large degree ;-) Or of pointers and references in general. Still, even my trivial "pointer class" example shows that it's good for generic code that stuff is not prohibited arbitrarily.

Comment: yes, I'm digressing here :)
I got your point anyway, and I think that I need to study templates more in order to get the answer right, thanks

Comment: @Luca In case it comes in handy, we keep a [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) here on SO.

Comment: thanks, I'm actually more than half-way through Lippmann's C++11 primer and I find it a very valid book. I think my next move will be tackling Stroustroup's bible, C++ programming language. I know Java and I'm keeping studying it as well, so it's quite challenging but I like it! ;)