# c++ rvalue reference forwarding performance

Tags: c++, c++11

I am doing some experiments to try to understand how forwarding works and I get to situation where I do not understand.

When I compile with clang 3.8 -O3

```
class Foo {
  Foo(const std::string& s) : str(s) {}
  std::string str;
};
```

and

```
class Foo {
  Foo(std::string&& s) : str(std::forward<std::string&>(s)) {}
  std::string str;
};
```

Constructing Foo with `Foo foo("this is a test")` in the first case is almost 2 times faster.

Why?

Comment: I'm guessing copy elision.

Comment: Do you mean `std::forward<std::string>(s)` (or simply `std::move(s)`) or `&` are here on purpose ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, with '&' it does not compile without it. "error: no matching function for call to 'forward'"

Comment: @gsf: Not sure what you mean, the 3 variants compile (&, &&, nothing) [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ec2344c9e222fe3).

Comment: Note that with `&`, you make a copy of the temporary

Comment: @Jarod42 Oops, sorry, the compile error was triggered from another test that was passing std::string("this is a test"). Without & is way better, just about 5% slower, but as it become clear from the answers using forward in this case is wrong anyways. I just did it because nothing else did any difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to perfect-forward using `std::forward` only when dealing with [forwarding references](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/). Forwarding references only exist in the context of template deduction.

`void f(std::string&& x)`: `x` is a regular rvalue-reference, because no template type deduction is taking place.

`template<typename T> void f(T&& x)`: `x` is a forwarding reference, because of `T` template deduction.

**Generally**, you don't want to use `std::forward` unless you're dealing with forwarding references.

When calling `std::forward`, you have to pass the exact type of the forwarded value. This can be done as such: `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)`.

Or as such, when you have a name for the deduced type:

```
template<typename T> 
void f(T&& x)
{
    something(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

I would write your code like this:

```
class Foo {
  template<typename T> 
  Foo(T&& s) 
      : str(std::forward<decltype(s)>(s)) {}

  std::string str;
};
```

Comment: Why would you write <decltype(s)> instead of <T>?

Comment: Mostly because I often find myself in situations where I do not have a `T` available - think of generic lambdas, for example. I therefore created a `#define FWD(x) ::std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` macro that helps me avoid repetition/mistakes. I think `<decltype(x)>(x)` is much less error-prone than `<T>(x)`, and the verbosity can be reduced with the aforementioned macro. Also, I cannot think of a context where `<decltype(x)>(x)` is unusable, but `<T>(x)` cannot be used in generic lambdas, for example.

Comment: Interesting, and I agree. Now, isn't `decltype(s)` `T&&` ? Is it that reference collapsing and the way `std::forward` works makes `<T>` and `<T&&>` do the same thing?

Comment: *"Never use `std::forward` unless you're dealing with forwarding references."*, why not? It's useful even in scenarios where template argument type deduction is not involved

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: "never" is probably an exaggeration *(I'll edit the post)*, yeah, but I cannot recall any instance of using `std::forward` outside of template argument deduction contexts. Could you provide a practical example?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo [How std::function works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14936539/3953764)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good example - I've actually used `forward` many times like that in my code, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is supposed to be a move constructor, and as such, should use `std::move`:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(std::string&& s) : str(std::move(s)) {}

  std::string str;
};
```

`std::forward` only makes sense for what Scott Myers calls "universal references", which is a subset of rvalue references - Vittorio talks about that in his answer.

Comment: Technically it's not a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), but of course OP should use `std::move` here.

Comment: It is different question, but with std::move it makes no difference, why?

Comment: @gsf: because the compiler is smart enough to do this optimization regardless of the code! It's called "copy elision".

Comment: I would expect a performance difference when compiled with `-O0`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe And with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: @vsoftco: good point. I'm not familiar with the advanced GCC optimization flags, `-O3` + `-flto` does the trick for me.